# Python paste text copied to clipboard on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy

Is there any way to paste the copied text from clipboard on android using python?
Pyperclip and tkinter doesn't work, so is there maybe a way to do this with kivy or something?

Comment: Since you tagged `kivy`, there's an API for that named [**Clipboard**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html#module-kivy.core.clipboard).

Comment: I was trying to do it with Clipboard, and it wasn't working for some reason, and I just found out, that Kivy 2.0 only supports Python 2.7 to 3.9, and i am using Python 3.10+. So switching to Python 3.9 solved the issue, and I can now use Clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using [kivy](https://kivy.org) (Kivy 2.0 only supports Python 2.7 to 3.9 at the moment, so make sure your Python version is compatible. Read more about installing **kivy** here: [Installing Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html)). There is module for this, called [Clipboard](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html#module-kivy.core.clipboard), and it can paste text from the users Clipboard.

```
#:import Clipboard kivy.core.clipboard.Clipboard

Button:
    on_release:
        self.text = Clipboard.paste()
        Clipboard.copy('Data')
```

Comment: Note that Kivy released version 2.2.1 in June 2023 which supports Python 3.7 to 3.11 (see https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.2.1).