# Button to copy text in Python available for everyone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot and, to make the UX better, I made a button that allows users to copy the value of an embed's field. I tested the code on my computer and the text gets copied, but as soon as I tried to click the button from my phone, the text didn't get copied.

Is there a way to render this button working on every Discord client (computer's clients and mobile's clients)?

However, the code I used is this

```py
from pyperclip import *

@ui.button(label="Copy ID", emoji="", style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="copy_id")
async def copy_id(self, button: ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):
    id = interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[4].value

    copy(id[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you are using for sending text to the clipboard is not maintained anymore ([here is their github](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip)).

I believe ([from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71100532/19069787)) that the [module Clipboard](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html#module-kivy.core.clipboard) of [Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html) may solve your problem. As of now, it support Python 3.7 to 3.10.